# React: Filtering a product with checkboxes

Tags: reactjs

I need to filter a product by `category`. The task seems simple, but I ran into a problem that the `category` parameter from the `data.jsx` file is an array, not a plain text value. So, just comparing by `id` will not work. Please help me to filter the product.

I've already done a small overwrite of the `selectedCategory` state where the checkboxes will be true.

[Demo codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/romantic-sound-46k6c4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A34%2C23&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as500063j6irxmg7601%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as400023j6ip7p0oawc%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as400033j6igsdmwl8b%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as400053j6ii0syeqye%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B45.458203836610004%252C54.541796163389996%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq6w8as400023j6ip7p0oawc%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as400023j6ip7p0oawc%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6zjxq100023j6i2kumjs1x%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A34%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A23%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A34%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A23%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq6zjxq100023j6i2kumjs1x%2522%257D%252C%2522clq6w8as400053j6ii0syeqye%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as400043j6ipx2icngv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as400053j6ii0syeqye%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as400043j6ipx2icngv%2522%257D%252C%2522clq6w8as400033j6igsdmwl8b%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq6w8as400033j6igsdmwl8b%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A27.767441498017305%257D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data has only the category labels, you can only filter the array by label text but first it will be easier if we map the selectedCategory array to a new one that only contains the labels

```
  const applyFilters = () => {
    const selectedCategories = selectedCategory.filter((cat) => cat.checked).map((cat) => cat.label);

    let updateList = products;
    if(selectedCategories.length > 0){
      updateList = products.filter((product) =>
        product.category.some((cat) => selectedCategories.includes(cat))
      );
    }

    setResult(updateList);
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, but nothing is filtering out :(

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/romantic-sound-46k6c4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot to first filter the selected categories after checked condition, I fixed the code sample

Comment: Thank you! And one more question, if you make filtering in reverse order. That is, to initially have the whole product, and further filtered by the selection of the checkbox. Where should I change the filtering, in `selectedCategories` or in `updateList`?

Comment: If I understand correctly you mean show all list if no filters applied. You could wrap the updateList filtering in an if to check if you have any filters checked, basically if selectedCategories length is not empty. I edited the code sample again to show an example.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot for the explanation and example! :)